# Can all classical optical materials be described by perturbation theory?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, perturbation-theory, non-linear-optics, non-perturbative

In quantum field theory (e.g. lattice QED), perturbation theory can "break down" when interactions become too strong.

Can something like that happen in classical non-linear optics? Can there be any combination of material (absurdly non-linear) and light (attosecond pulses, petawatt lasers, etc.) which can (somehow) be described by classical electrodynamics but the usual "expansion of polarization density inside the material in powers of electric field" (maybe later adding magnetic field as well...) breaks down and doesn't work? I.e., where no finite expansion order gives a reasonable description?

Alternatively, if the "describable clasically" assumption is weird in this context, is there a regime where some very strong coupling leads to the perturbative non-linear optics approach breaking down for a *stable bulk material that can be produced on earth*?

I mostly care about "shooting light at something and describing the light that comes out".

I've read claims about high harmonic generation (HHG) being such a phenomenon but it's not really clear to me how/why the perturbation theory (at any finite order!) does not apply. You can do it in bulk crystals but I guess the "classical system" restriction would not apply there, as it is usually described using some semi-classical models? For example, [Wikipedia on "nonlinear optics"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_optics) writes about some series "not converging" but it's not quite clear what is meant there. Some articles on HHG (e.g. [this](https://doi.org/10.1038/s41467-020-16133-8)) use the phrase "non-perturbative" but what exactly do they mean by that?

Comment: When the applied electric field is equal or greater than the inter-atomic field ionization occurs, and the electron can be pulled arbitrarily far from the atom. The induced dipole moment therefore diverges and you cannot describe the dynamics perturbatively because all the orders of the Taylor series contribute. Have a look at Ch. 1.2 of [this text](https://ufox.cfel.de/sites/sites_cfelgroups/site_cfel-ufox/content/e16281/e86791/e86980/e86982/infoboxContent86984/Manuscript_NLObis23122016.pdf). You can't model free electrons as being bound to atoms, that's why the model breaks down.